# how to use YUI to make a real mouse click event in a select tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, yui

I am trying to automate a html page where there is form needs to be filled.

There is a select tag in form, when user click and select a option in it, it will trigger the page to show another input field.

When I use the following code

```
$([name=selectTagName]).val('valueThatIneed')
```

It select the option as expected, but the input field won't show up unless you actually use your mouse to click on that option.

Updated:
Now I find that page actually wrote in YUI. But I am not familiar with framework.
So the question becomes how to do this in a YUI way, not jquery.

Comment: You should provide related HTML and JS.

Comment: Try to triggle the option's click event instead of the select event.

Comment: @FlyingFisher I tried, It won't work. would you mind take a look at Barmar's answer and the comment that I wrote?

Comment: You need show more code for someone to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Trigger the `select`'s `change` event:

```
$("[name=selectTagName]").val('valueThatIneed').trigger("change");
```

I'm assuming that the action you want is bound to the select's `change` event. If it's on a different event, trigger that instead.

Comment: is there a way to know what kind of event that select tag emit when I click on it? Because I don't program that form, so I don't kwon what kind of action that I am looking at.

Comment: Clicking on it causes a `click` event, and if you select a different value it causes a `change` event. But what matters is what event the code that shows the other input field is looking for. There's no way to know that without reading the code.

Comment: I think that Event simulation (http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/simulate.html) is more general solution, isn't it?